# Referring to one property within another within the Nagios NRPE config file (nrpe.cfg)

Tags: nagios, nrpe

So I have a slightly offbeat question that even Google (and stackoverflow) had already answered. So here goes.

This is on a monitored host, and specifically about the NRPE config file (nrpe.cfg). If I have two properties defined here like this:

```
..
server_address=10.68.10.2
..
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,100.0.254,10.68.10.2
..
```

Is it possible for me to change this on something on the lines of follows

```
..
server_address=10.68.10.2
..
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,100.0.254,$server_address
..
```

In other words, is it somehow possible to refer one property from another -in the same CFG file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just circling back for anyone else who may come back here. It still isn't and will never be possible.

Nagios' NRPE group looked into my request and decided it isn't worthwhile.

See: https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nrpe/issues/141

Answer (score 0):

***No***, but this is a Good Idea.

Can you open an Issue on the [NRPE GitHub](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nrpe)?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This has now been done at [this link](https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nrpe/issues/141).